# 802.11 action frames send/receive

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct, esp8266

Is it possible to gain access to 802.11 action frames TX/RX from software? There's a proprietary protocol based on vendor-specific action frames called ESP-NOW for ESP8266 and ESP32 chips, and I'd like to try to implement it on a Raspberry Pi.

As far as I understand, WiFi Direct is based on something like that.

Comment: Since this isn't specifically a Raspberry Pi question, but one that is more IoT/WiFi oriented in general, you might get better results posting it to https://iot.stackexchange.com.  Good luck in your quest!

Comment: @mrchips Thank you for redirecting. Perhaps I should somehow close the question here?

Comment: If you find a good answer somewhere else, just put an answer into this question here that points to it.  That way if someone else gets to this one in a search result, it will point them in the right direction.